# How to group points by distance and plot a minimum circle with a constant radius with centroid in the grouping

Tags: qgis, expression, geometry-generator

I am working with the following expression to try to draw a minimal circle of constant radius that groups the points by nearest:

```
minimal_circle (
    convex_hull( 
        collect(
            $geometry, 
            group_by:=overlay_nearest(@layer, $id, max_distance:=350, limit:=15))
        )
        )
```

I have tried to use `max_distance` and `limit` variables but the expression does not work as I expect and does not draw anything:

[image]

The target I am trying to achieve is the one shown in this simulated screenshot:

[image]

I have found an alternative based on KMeans clusters. It involves calculating the "CLUSTER_ID" and grouping by this field. However, I would like to avoid with the clusters pre-calculation and be able to keep a constant radius for all circles:

[image]

Comment: I think the expression you're looking for is the following one, `minimal_circle(convex_hull(collect_geometries(overlay_nearest(@layer,$geometry,max_distance:=350, limit:=15))))`. But you wont get the expected result without aggregating to retrieve one circle per group of points, and to do that you'll need some type of clustering. Otherwise you'll get just a circle enclosing the points that are in a radius of 350 map units for each point.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the expression Mayo.
I confirm your comment that it seems that some kind of grouping cluster is needed to filter the circles.